# How can I mount a folder from the host to a Docker container with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `Dockerfile.aws.json`:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Ports": [{
        "ContainerPort": "5000",
        "HostPort": "5000"
    }],
    "Volumes": [{
        "HostDirectory": "/tmp/download/models",
        "ContainerDirectory": "/models"
    }],
    "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

In `.ebextensions/download.config`, I have:

```
sources:
  /tmp/download: https://example.com/models.zip
```

But in my container, `/models` never gets created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the issue, but could not. In my tests the `Volumes` work as expected.

However, you can do some troubleshooting using [runlike](https://github.com/lavie/runlike) tool to inspect the command used to actually run your container. The tool allow you to check if the EB correctly mounts the volume:

> docker run --name=funny_driscoll --hostname=628fc70a4331 --env=PORT=8080 --env=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin **--volume=/tmp/fffff:/models** --expose=8080 --restart=no --detach=true eb14d2391001 ./testapp

To use it, login to the EB instance and install it:

```
sudo yum install python-pip

sudo pip install runlike

# check running container
sudo docker ps 

# inspect the docker run command
runlike <container_id>
```

This will enable to **confirm** whether the `docker run` correctly contains `--volume=` as well as other configuration options.

Comment: It seems that you can't use `.ebextensions` and `Dockerfile.aws.json`. My latest issue is https://stackoverflow.com/q/62818496/239879 if you have any insight?

Comment: @Shamoon Thanks. I saw the other issue, but haven't attempted to replicate it yet. The `volume` issue took me a while to double check :-)

Comment: I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Shamoon No problem. Later I will try to find some time and inspect closer the other issue and see if I can provide any insights.

Comment: Quick Q: What if /models already exists in my Container? Will it overwrite?

Comment: @Shamoon When you run container with ` --volume`, the existing `/mount` is simply not used. It will point to host directory  mapped. So in a sense, its overwritten.