# How do I get a Command to run from a Dockerfile.aws.json on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `Dockerfile` and a `Dockerfile.aws.json`:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Ports": [{
        "ContainerPort": "5000",
        "HostPort": "5000"
    }],
    "Volumes": [{
        "HostDirectory": "/tmp/download/models",
        "ContainerDirectory": "/models"
    }],
    "Logging": "/var/log/nginx",
    "Command": "mkdir -p /tmp && axel https://example.com/models.zip -o /tmp/models.zip"
}
```

But when I deploy, it doesn't run the `Command` that I specified. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile, than the `Command` gets appended as its [arguments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html):

> Specify a command to execute in the container. If you specify an Entrypoint, then Command is added as an **argument to Entrypoint**. For more information, see CMD in the Docker documentation.

Thus your Command `mkdir -p /tmp ...` will be used as an argument to `python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0`, resulting in error. This could explain why you experience issue.

I tried to **recreate the issue** initially using your `Command` structure but had some problems. What worked was using `Command` in the following way:

```
"Command": "/bin/bash -c \"mkdir -p /tmp && axel https://example.com/models.zip -o /tmp/models.zip\""
```

My `Dockerfile` did not have `Entrypoint`. Thus to run your python you could maybe do the following (assuming everything else is correct):

```
"Command": "/bin/bash -c \"mkdir -p /tmp && axel https://example.com/models.zip -o /tmp/models.zip && python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Dockerfile content?
It most likely they your `ENTRYPOINT` script does not receive parameters, or it is ignoring it.

What you can do is something similar to [this](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data).

You have an entrypoint script that receive the command passed in aws.json as parameter, execute it and then call your real python command.

Or you can replace your `ENTRYPOINT` by something similar to this:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]`

and your default command will be:

`CMD ["python3 ..."]`

This way when running locally you only run the python3 command.

When running in aws, you can change your Command and append the python to the end, as mentioned by Marcin.  Both cases works

Comment: In my `Dockerfile`, I have: `ENTRYPOINT python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: But I want to run that `Command` before the `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically you can override the entrypoint to execute the command before.

Comment: So then in my `Dockerfile`, I should change my `ENTRYPOINT` to some shell script and then in my `Dockerfile.aws.json`, I should have `"Command": "--deploy"`?